GridDB - Finding node definition file (gs_node.json)
I have a running node service in GridDB
● gridstore.service - GridDB database server.
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-08-15 17:15:16 PKT; 8min ago
   Main PID: 303 (gsserver)
      Tasks: 35 (limit: 9487)
     Memory: 143.9M ()
     CGroup: /system.slice/gridstore.service
             └─303 /usr/bin/gsserver --conf /var/lib/gridstore/conf

And I wanted to know some information of my running node service from its definition file (gs_node.json):

/sql/serviceAddress

/sql/publicServiceAddress

/serviceAddress

/dataStore/dbPath

/dataStore/backupPath


I have tried it to get from the initial configuration directory of GS_HOME (/var/lib/gridstore). But I cannot find it on the directory. Can anyone know, how/where I can get that Json file?
